# Why is array not updating after sorting in React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React. The array in state is updating only once after sort function. Why is it not updated again after the sort function is triggered second time?

```
const [cases, setCases] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

let sortDown = true
let sorted = []

    function sort(){
        const copy = [...cases]
        if(sortDown){
            sorted = copy.sort(function(a, b){
                return b - a 
            })
        } else {
            sorted = copy.sort(function(a, b){
                return a - b
            })
        }
        sortDown = !sortDown
        setCases(sorted)
    }
```

Comment: Please show your full code, with the calls to `sort()`

Comment: Sort directly manipulate the array. You don't need to keep the sorted array into a new array. the ```copy``` array is sorted. So use ```setCases(copy)``` instead.

Comment: No one can't answer "why the sort is triggered twice" without showing how you call this function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

React rerenders the component when props or state changed. In your case, you declare `sorted` array and then you pass it to setCases. So for the first time setCases takes `sorted` array and it is new value for that. Then you sort the values again and you mutate the `sorted` array and pass it again to setCases. But setCases doesn't consider `sorted` as a new array because it was mutated so the reference was not changed. For React it is still the same array you passed at first time. You need to return new array and then pass it to `setCases`.

The other thing you should do is to store sortDown in state. Otherwise it will be reintialized every render.
Following code should work in your case:

```
    const [cases, setCases] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
    const [sortDown, setSortDown] = useState(true)

        function sort(){
            const copy = [...cases] // create copy of cases array (new array is created each time function is called)
            if(sortDown){
                copy.sort(function(a, b){ // mutate copy array
                    return b - a 
                })
            } else {
                copy.sort(function(a, b){
                    return a - b
                })
            }
            setSortDown(!sortDown); // set new value for sortDown
            setCases(copy); // pass array to setCases
        }
```

Comment: setSortDown(!sortDown); - avoid this

Answer (score 5):

You should be using a state variable to decide sortType.

otherwise it'll be reinitialized every render.

```
  const [cases, setCases] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
  const [sortDown, setSortDown] = useState(true);

  function sort() {
    const copy = [...cases];
    if (sortDown) {
      copy.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b - a;
      });
    } else {
      copy.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
      });
    }
    setSortDown((prev) => !prev);
    setCases(copy);
  }
```

Comment: What changes did you make? Please explain your answer

Comment: sortDown is state variable now.

Comment: Sorting can be made simpler when you use direction that can either be 1 or -1: `[...cases].sort((a, b) => (a - b) * direction)`